# New toolbar for editing in Vector: How to get?

Tags: mediawiki

Using [MediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/) 1.16 with the Vector skin (fresh installation, no upgrades or imports), **how do I get that new fancy Ajax-enabled editing toolbar?**

[image: Cool editor that I want]

I've digged through all available settings in php, but whatever I do, I get the old monobook-style toolbar:

[image: Measly editor that I have]

Apparently, this is not a caching issue, as I was able to use [this method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki:Common.js/edit.js) to add more buttons to this toolbar.

Currently I have the following customizations:

```
$wgDefaultSkin = 'vector';
$wgUseAjax = true;
$wgEnableMWSuggest = true;   # Enable ajax suggestions for search box
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['edit'] = false;   # Disable anonymous edits
```

I've also enabled short URLs as described [here](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Short_urls#Setup_steps).

Everything else on my wiki looks definitely like Vector. It's just the toolbar.

The official manual seems to be making a good laugh out of me, as this new fancy toolbar said to be "the default" for the Vector skin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that the new toolbar is an experimental feature that you have to install: [http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:UsabilityInitiative](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aUsabilityInitiative)